# Application freezes when I do resuming - Windows 10 Mobile - C#

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, freeze, resume, windows-10-mobile

When I open the app (Universal app Windows 10 / windows 10 Mobile), this work perfect but when Go Back using native hardware back key until exit application, the application freeze when i do resuming (long press back key and select the app exit before).

I have the build 10572. The same app, in PC version, works perfect. 
It will problem with build mobile, since it is still preview? Or the problem are using native hardware back key to exit application?

The strange thing is that when I "Run" through Visual Studio, the application does not freeze, but when I run out of VS application has this problem!

Someone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have something in *Resuming* event? Have you tried to debug this even (Lifecycle events -> Suspend/Resume)?

Comment: Hi. I resolve this situation. Do acivate() aplication when the state is"Suspended". Work :)
Thanks

Comment: At what event you call activate(). You mean *Window.Current.Activate()*?